# Check attribute value of XML element with a regular expression pattern

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have this code, which does not work.

I want to iterate trough all `p` elements below the `body` element and look for an element named `object`. Then use the `match()` function to look for a certain pattern in the attribute node data.

```
<xsl:template match="/xhtml:html/xhtml:body//xhtml:p">
    <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:object[matches(@data,'*mov$')]">
        <halloMovie><xsl:value-of select="@data"/></halloMovie>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Error message while executing with matches()

> [xslt] : Fatal Error! Could not compile stylesheet Cause: Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(matches, [step("attribute", 17), literal-expr(v$)])'.

If I use the following line with the `contains()` function which works.

```
<xsl:for-each select="xhtml:object[contains(@data,'.mov')]">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `matches` function requires XPath 2.0 (and hence XSLT 2.0) or later, there's no regular expression support in XSLT 1.0.

If you just want to check that the value ends with ".mov" you can do that using the substring function

```
substring(@data, string-length(@data) - 3) = '.mov'
```

(XPath 1.0 has `starts-with` but you need 2.0 for `ends-with`).

Comment: Thanks, I had this in mind that matches is xpath 2.0 and so not to use in xslt 1.0. I was just not sure. Your answer confirms it. And thanks for the alternative solution. I like it.

Comment: @DanielStutz the _only_ functions you have available to you in XSLT 1.0 are those listed in the [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib) and [XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#add-func) specifications (plus any processor-specific extensions).  The much broader function library at http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/ is v2.0+ only.